# Randomly drawing socks out of a bag

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 5 pairs of socks in a bag, so a total of 10 socks. Each pair of socks is of a different color from the others. After having randomly drawn 4 socks from the bag, what's the probability of picking 4 socks of different colors?

My answer was to first get the total number of possible draws as ${10 \choose 4} = 210$.

Then I'd proceed to compute the number of possible pickings of 2 pairs of socks out of the 4 draws:
${4 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2} = 36$.

Similarly, the number of pickings of 1 pair of socks + 2 loose socks would be ${4 \choose 2} {4 \choose 1} {4 \choose 1} = 96$.

The probability of picking 4 socks of different colours would then be the complementary set of events to the sum of the previous 2: $P($ no matching pair $) = 1 - \frac{36 + 96}{210} = 0.372$.

However the answer to the problem points to a different result. I understand the fact there are 5 colors should factor in somewhere, I only considered the number 4 (the draws) in my combinatorics and I guess this is the source of my mistake.

Comment: There are $10$ possible choices for the two pairs ($\binom 52=10$).  Not sure where your $36$ comes from.

Comment: I think a direct count is easier anyway.  There are $5$ ways to choose the $4$ pairs of socks you wish to choose from.  Then two choices from each pair.  Hence $5\times 2^4$.

Comment: Your $96$ is also wrong and should be $120$

Comment: What do you think it means to get a probability of $36$ or $96$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you do not need to do these cumbersome calculations .Let me show you another approach. Lets show the socks using boxes ,  each adjacent boxes represent same color.

$$\color{red}{\fbox{1}\fbox{2}}\quad\color{blue}{\fbox{3}\fbox{4}}\quad\color{green}{\fbox{5}\fbox{6}}\quad\color{orange}{\fbox{7}\fbox{8}}\quad\color{purple}{\fbox{9}\fbox{10}}$$

Now assume that we have some stickers which we use to select which sock will be selected. When we put these stickers onto these boxes , it will mean that we will select that box ,i.e, that sock.

- In the beginning , we can select any of them  , so we have $$\frac{10}{10}=1$$
- Assume that we select the box $2$ , then we cannot select box $1$ , because all selected boxes must be different colors. Then , we have $8$ choices among $9$ possible boxes such that $$\frac{8}{9}$$
- Now ,assume that we put the sticker onto the box $5$ ,so there left $6$ possible choices among $8$ boxes , so $$\frac{6}{8}$$
- Assume that assume that the sticker has been put onto box $10$ , now we have $4$ suitable choices among $7$ , so $$\frac{4}{7}$$

Now , it is the time for finding their product such that $$1 \times \frac{8}{9}\times \frac{6}{8}\times \frac{4}{7 }= \frac{24}{63}=0.380952381$$

Comment: Yellow does not show up well.  I suggest switching to orange.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig edited ...

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but I think TonyK explained it more clearly.  You talk about a particular sequence of choices, but what you really mean is that we must select a different color with each succeeding choice.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is not the easiest, but if followed correctly does give the answer.

If the number of selections is ${10 \choose 4}=210$ equally likely possibilities

then the number of ways of getting two pairs is ${5 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}^2=10$

and the number of ways of getting one pair is ${5 \choose 1}{2 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}^2 = 120$

leaving $210-10-120=80$ ways of getting no pairs, or directly as lulu commented ${5 \choose 4}{2 \choose 1}^4=80$

and a probability of $\frac{80}{210}=\frac{8}{21}\approx 0.381$.

Comment: I suggest adding the direct count since it is easier and mentioning that it is the method lulu described in the comments.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have added "directly"

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the second sock is a new colour is $\frac89$.
The probability that the third sock is a new colour is $\frac68$.
The probability that the fourth sock is a new colour is $\frac47$.

And that's all you need.

Comment: what is the difference between mine and yours ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur: Yours is five times longer, and requires a supply of stickers.